# Flink CEP not Working in event time but working in Processing Time

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink, complex-event-processing, flink-cep

When I am using Flink CEP code for processing time (which is by default config) I am able to get the required patter match but while configuring the env to Event Time I am unable to get any pattern match.

```
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)
    env.enableCheckpointing(3000) // checkpoint every 3000 msec
     val lines = env.addSource(consumerKafkaSource.consume("bank_transaction_2", "192.168.2.201:9092", "192.168.2.201:2181", "http://192.168.2.201:8081"))

  val eventdate = ExtractAndAssignEventTime.assign(lines, "unix", "datetime", 3) //Extracting date time here

    val event = eventdate.keyBy(v => v.get("customer_id").toString.toInt)
   val pattern1 = Pattern.begin[GenericRecord]("start").where(v=>v.get("state").toString=="FAILED").next("d").where(v=>v.get("state").toString=="FAILED")
      val patternStream = CEP.pattern(event, pattern1)
    val warnID = patternStream.sideOutputLateData(latedata).select(value =>  {
      val v = value.mapValues(c => c.toList.toString)
      Json(DefaultFormats).write(v).replace("\\\"", "\"")
        //.replace("List(","{").replace(")","}")
    })
    val latedatastream = warnID.getSideOutput(latedata)
    latedatastream.print("late_data")


    warnID.print("warning")
    event.print("event")
```

Timestamp extraction code

```
object ExtractAndAssignEventTime {
  def assign(stream:DataStream[GenericRecord],timeFormat:String,timeColumn:String,OutofOrderTime:Int ):DataStream[GenericRecord] ={
    if(!(timeFormat.equalsIgnoreCase("Unix"))){
      val EventTimeStream=stream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor[GenericRecord](Time.seconds(3)) {
        override def extractTimestamp(t: GenericRecord): Long = {
          new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(timeFormat).parse(t.get(timeColumn).toString).getTime
        }
      })
      EventTimeStream
    }
    else{
      val EventTimeStream=stream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor[GenericRecord](Time.seconds(OutofOrderTime)) {
        override def extractTimestamp(t: GenericRecord): Long = {
          (t.get(timeColumn).toString.toLong)
        }
      })
      EventTimeStream
    }
  }
```

Please help me solve this issue. Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since You are using the `AssingerWithPeriodicWatermark` You also need to set up the `setAutowatermarkInterval` so that Flink will use this interval to generate watermarks.

You can do this by calling `env.getConfig.setAutoWatermarkInterval([interval])`.

For Event Time CEP bases on Watermarks so If they are not generated then there will be basically no output.

Comment: Hi Dominik, Thanks for the response, but if the watermark are generated at certain interval which is set in the env.config, how will the BoundedOutofOrderness work??

Comment: At each interval, the Watermark will be generated that is equal to the currently `currentMaxTimestamp - outOfOrderness` :) So that the outOfOrderness is actually how long can be element late according to the element with highest timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I "solved" it just now, but the answer doesn't make much sense (at least to me), as you'll see.

### Explanation:

In my original code, I had this:

```scala
var env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)
env.setParallelism(1)
env.getConfig.setAutoWatermarkInterval(1)

...

var stream : DataStream[String] = env.readTextFile("/home/luca/Desktop/input")
    
    
var tupleStream = stream.map(new S2TMapFunction())
tupleStream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new PlacasPunctualTimestampAssigner())

val pattern = Pattern.begin[(String,Double,Double,String,Int,Int)]("follow").where(new SameRegionFunction())

val patternStream = CEP.pattern(newTupleStream,pattern)

val result = patternStream.process(new MyPatternProcessFunction())
```

Acording to my logging, I saw that neither `SameRegionFunction` nor `MyPatternProcessFunction` were being executed, what is very unexpected, to say the least.

### Answer:

Since I was clueless, I decided to test making my stream go through one more transformation function, just to check if my events really were being inserted in the stream. So, I submitted `tupleStream` to a map operation, generating `newTupleStream`, like this:

```scala
var env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)
env.setParallelism(1)
env.getConfig.setAutoWatermarkInterval(1)

...

var stream : DataStream[String] = env.readTextFile("/home/luca/Desktop/input")


/* I created 'DoNothingMapFunction', where the output event = input event*/
var tupleStream = stream.map(new S2TMapFunction())
var newTupleStream = tupleStream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new PlacasPunctualTimestampAssigner()).map(new DoNothingMapFunction())


val pattern = Pattern.begin[(String,Double,Double,String,Int,Int)]("follow").where(new SameRegionFunction())

val patternStream = CEP.pattern(newTupleStream,pattern)

val result = patternStream.process(new MyPatternProcessFunction())
```

And then `SameRegionFunction` and `MyPatternProcessFunction` decided to run.

#### Obs:

I changed the line:

```scala
var newTupleStream = tupleStream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new PlacasPunctualTimestampAssigner()).map(new DoNothingMapFunction())
```

to this:

```scala
var newTupleStream = tupleStream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new PlacasPunctualTimestampAssigner())
```

and it also worked. Apparently just another level of indirection is enough to make it work, although it's not clear to me why it happens.